# Java AudioClip - no sound, no error

Tags: java, audio, applet

I've read prior issues about java AudioClip and have done my research, yet I still cannot figure out why this
AudioClip does not play. The .wav clip plays fine in Eclipse IDE, it is also in the appropriate directory; if the file
is in the incorrect directory this code snippet throws an error message.

My professor asked that we play the audioClip using this format also, `audioClip = Applet.newAudioClip(new File(filePath).toURI().toURL());`

When executed the play method at the bottom does get invoked however NO SOUND! 
Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

public class PlaySoundApplet extends Applet implements ActionListener
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Button play,stop;
    AudioClip audioClip;

  public void init()
  {
      play = new Button("Play");
      add(play);
      play.addActionListener(this);

      stop = new Button("Stop");
      add(stop);
      stop.addActionListener(this);

      try
      {  
          String filePath = "." + File.separator + "audio" + File.separator + "island_music.wav";

          File file = new File(filePath);

          if (file.exists())
          {
              audioClip = Applet.newAudioClip(file.toURI().toURL());
          }
          else
          {
              throw new RuntimeException("Directory " + filePath + " does not exist"); //debugging
          }
      }
      catch (MalformedURLException malformedURLException)
      {
          throw new RuntimeException("Malformed URL: " + malformedURLException);  //debugging
      }
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
  {
      Button source = (Button)ae.getSource();

      if (source.getLabel() == "Play")
      {
          audioClip.play();
          System.out.println("Play was executed");
      }
      else if(source.getLabel() == "Stop")
      {
          audioClip.stop();
          System.out.println("Stop was executed");
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: *"does get invoked however NO SOUND!"*  DON'T SHOUT!  Try the code with the simple [`leftright.wav`](http://pscode.org/media/#sound).  Does your homework specify that this must be an applet?

Comment: Wow... the leftright.wav works!! So I am guessing I have to try a different type of .wav file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code with the simple [leftright.wav](http://pscode.org/media/#sound).

> ..the leftright.wav works!!

Most media formats (sound, image, video etc.) are what is known as 'container formats'.  The encoding of the media might be in any number of types.  Java reads some encodings, but not others.

> So I am guessing I have to try a different type of .wav file?

If it is for an application resource, I'd tend to convert the current WAV to a type that is compatible with Java Sound.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean after you build your program and run it the sound doesn't play? You should either embed the wav file into your resource folder and use getResources() to find the file. Or the other option would be to scan your local directory to find the file object with a matching name and file extension.

Also you are throwing the Malformed URL exception so you wont get an error if the URL is wrong. You shouldn't throw it, use `try {...} catch (MalformedURLException mex) { system.out.println(mex.getMessage()) }` instead.

Comment: If a malformed was thrown I would see a message in the console, however it was never thrown to begin with.